# Are all genetic instructions in DNA?

Tags: genetics, dna

[Wiki says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA)

> DNA is a molecule that carries most of the genetic instructions used
>   in the growth, development, functioning and reproduction of all known
>   living organisms and many viruses.

What bugs me is the "most" there, it implies some of the genetic instructions are elsewhere, but where?

Comment: Are all _____ instructions in DNA.. Genetic: yes. Inheritable: no.

Comment: Would you please expand on that, or give me a general direction on where to look for?

Comment: maybe you mean [histone modification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histone)

Comment: Genetic information specifically means DNA or RNA in case of certain viruses. There are, however, other information that can be inherited which include cytoplasmic factors like mRNAs, proteins, vesicles etc. Check maternal inheritance.

Comment: Generally, in Biology it is better to use "most". Because we can't be sure that we have done a complete research about it. And about your question:
Yes. But note that the whole genetic instructions are NOT located in the Nucleus(of course, in eukaryotic cells like ours). Also note that some genes like Metabolic Enzymes's Genes are located in the Mitochondria(and the Chloroplast in Plant cells).

Comment: Food for thought: If you just have DNA, you can't set and forget a cell. The genes have all the information, but you have to *borrow* proteins that are already there from cells that already exist (and you get these during cell divisions, like DNA/RNA polymerases). This is a sort of cellular memory.

Comment: I don't know why it says "most". I think it is misleading and it should be written "all" (or "most" should be removed). Note though, that the genetic information of an individual is (in most species) is contained in more than a single DNA molecule, which makes the sentence even more confusing. Note also, that in eukaryotes (which includes plants, funghi, animals and some others but does not include bacteria and viruses), there are DNA in the nucleus and DNA in the mitochondrion (and other double-membrane organelles).

Comment: @Remi.b The statement is fair, especially if you are willing to consider RNA viruses as a form of life. Also, if you think about Maternal Effect in embryonic development, these are usually mRNA gradients that are established prior to fertilization and have a significant effect on embryonic patterning and axis formation. While the genes are expressed from DNA initially, they are not expressed by the organism that develops, so you can argue that these instructions are RNA-based, as they were expressed in the parent organism and not the resulting organism.

Answer (score 3):

Genetic information is the heritable information used by organisms to guide their self-assembly. It's why traits can persist across generations. DNA is, by far, the primary material used (by life) to encode genetic information, but it's not the only one. RNA is a pretty common alternative to DNA.

If we're looking to Wikipedia, this is actually referred to (in passing) on many pages about genetics. They usually link to the page on the best known edge case, [RNA viruses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_virus):

> An RNA virus is a virus that has RNA (ribonucleic acid) as its genetic material. This nucleic acid is usually single-stranded RNA (ssRNA) but may be double-stranded RNA (dsRNA). Notable human diseases caused by RNA viruses include Ebola hemorrhoragic fever, SARS, influenza, hepatitis C, West Nile fever, polio, and measles.

While viruses fall into a weird middle ground between life and inanimacy, they still all need genes, and many of them use RNA for that. Side note: retroviruses get their name from the fact that they use [reverse transcription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_transcriptase#Process_of_reverse_transcription) to synthesize DNA from an RNA template.

Comment: I guess that's excluded where it says "many viruses" instead of "all viruses"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to being excluded (too many pronouns), but 1) biology is full of exceptions, and 2) many viruses store their genes in DNA.

Comment: RNA is an alternative, not a complement, by using "many viruses" I think wiki rules out RNA viruses from that sentence. The use of "most" suggests that there is a complement. About mitochondrial DNA, it's still DNA. So it probably is just a wording mistake in wiki or a misinterpretation by me as so far I know of no such complement.

Comment: @erik Maternal effect genes during embryonic development are set up in the oocyte prior to fertilization on mRNA. Obviously these genes are found on maternal chromosomes (DNA), but they are not expressed by the oocyte or the embryo, so technically the instructions are stored on RNA and the RNA is heritable, They may also be referring to epigenetic modifications, though there is still a bit more controversy about whether or not those are heritable.